# pandas .rolling().mean() analog in C#

Tags: python, c#, pandas

I'm trying to convert the following python code which calculates ATR using EMA into C#.

```py
def calc_atr(df, high, low, close, timeperiod=14):
    df['H_L'] = df[high] - df[low]
    df['H_Cp'] = abs(df[high] - df[close].shift(1))
    df['L_Cp'] = abs(df[low] - df[close].shift(1))
    df['TR'] = df[["H_L", "H_Cp", "L_Cp"]].max(axis=1)
    df['ATR'] = df['TR'].rolling(timeperiod).mean()
    for i in range(timeperiod , len(df)):
        df.loc[i, 'ATR'] = (df.loc[i - 1, 'ATR'] * (timeperiod -1) + df.loc[i, 'TR']) / timeperiod

    return df
```

This is my attempt but I'm not doing the rolling window mean correctly. I think there was a way with LINQ, but I'm not sure how.

```cs
public static void CalcAtr(this List<Candle> source, int period = 14)
{
    var highs = source.Select(e => e.High).ToArray();
    var lows = source.Select(e => e.Low).ToArray();
    var closes = source.Select(e => e.Close).ToArray();

    var atr = new decimal[source.Count];

    for (int i = period; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        var hl = highs[i] - lows[i];
        var hcp = Math.Abs(highs[i] - closes[i - 1]);
        var lcp = Math.Abs(lows[i] - closes[i - 1]);

        var tr = Math.Max(hl, Math.Max(hcp, lcp));

        atr[i] = (atr[i - 1] * (period - 1) + tr) / period;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know what it does, but can't reproduce it using LINQ

Comment: Ah I see. I misunderstood your question.